# Touch to return to facebook return button

Tags: buttons, indicator

I have been trying to think of some other UX methods for moving from one app to the other with ease of use and not getting the user over cluttered with button and icons since the system I am designing is already extremely complex. I have found facebook do this excellent method when moving from messenger app to fb app. Does anyone have any other suggestions that pose this feature. the app is for **Desktop & ipad**

Answer (score 1):

I like how Gmail (iOS) handles it.
If you open a link within Gmail, it'll take you to Chrome browser.
Instead of a back arrow button which normally appears on the browser toolbar, it'll become a button with the text 'Gmail' (as shown in image), hinting that this is the earliest page and if you go back one step more you'll go back to Gmail.
It's clear while remains the conventional look of a navigation bar, and almost takes no extra space.

However, not every app is suit for it. It works better with ones that already have a nav bar.

[image: Gmail to Chrome navigation]

Comment: This is a great option for apps (mobile/tablet) but might not be a great solution for desktop.

Comment: It might be easier to provide suggestion if you describe the type and platform of the desktop app. Thx.